# Shopware 6: Docker exec chown fails in Git Bash script with "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, docker, git-bash, shopware6, chown

I have a Git Bash script that runs some Docker commands to set up my Shopware container. One of the commands uses `docker exec` to run `sudo chown` on a path inside the container:

```rb
docker exec -it $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID sudo chown www-data /var/www/html/custom/plugins/shopware-ai-demodata/src/Service/Generator/
```

This works fine when the command is run inside the container using the docker desktop. However, if I run the script, it gives an error in Git Bash (Windows OS):

```rb
chown: cannot access 'C:/Program Files/Git/var/www/html/custom/plugins/shopware-ai-demodata/src/Service/Generator/': No such file or directory
```

It seems like it is trying to run chown directly on my Windows host instead of inside the Docker container since the path clearly doesn't exist natively on Windows. How can I make this command work inside the shopware container via script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Git bash trying to expand things like `/bin/sh` to an executable in its own path. To disable it, you double the first slash:

```bash
docker exec -it $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID sudo chown www-data //var/www/html/custom/plugins/shopware-ai-demodata/src/Service/Generator/
```